# All the logarithms of a non-singular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms

I'm reading some notes on dynamical systems that talk about matrix logarithms with little to no detail on the subject. I read the wikipedia article and others on the internet, but not all is clear.

I saw some formulas for the $n\times n$ case, but which are **all** the logarithms of a two-by-two non-singular matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you are going to find anything so straightforward than [*Logarithm of a matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix). They have trivial examples there.

You might have a look at this paper by [*Nicholas Higham, IMPROVED INVERSE SCALING AND SQUARING ALGORITHMS FOR THE MATRIX LOGARITHM*](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1851/01/covered/MIMS_ep2011_83.pdf). It includes a very difficult 4x4 example for the method described.

Here is a [*online calculator*](http://calculator-fx.com/calculator/linear-algebra/matrix-logarithm) that allows you to start with a 3x3 and scale up, but I cannot attest to its goodness.

If you have a CAS, like Mathematica, it has a MatrixLog command and maybe that command can accept general inputs for an nxn matrix, so you might want to look into that.

Comment: I was not aware of this calculator, thanks, +1.

Comment: @julien: Thanks! regards

Comment: We all learn something from your posts (OPs and users alike, as you can see!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula:

$\ln \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}-a+d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)+\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a-d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} & \frac{b \left(\ln \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)-\ln \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} \\
 \frac{c \left(\ln \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)-\ln \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} & \frac{\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a-d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)+\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}-a+d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$